# MySQL select within a select

Tags: mysql, select, join

I am not even sure if the title is right, apologies if not!

I have a MySQL DB that holds the details of Wi-Fi devices collected from several Access points.

My `SELECT` statement below returns all devices found within a 1 hour time period:

```
SELECT mac 
  FROM TBLWiFi 
GROUP BY 
       mac 
HAVING COUNT( mac ) >1 
       AND TIMESTAMP >= DATE_SUB( NOW( ) , INTERVAL 1 HOUR )
)
```

The results look like this:

```
╔═══════════════════╦══════════════════╦═════════════╗
║ mac               ║ timestamp        ║ reportedby  ║
╠═══════════════════╬══════════════════╬═════════════╣
║ B0:02:94:1D:3B:43 ║ 21/03/2014 12:27 ║ AP-3c9b33d0 ║
║ C0:3E:0F:0F:2D:EB ║ 21/03/2014 12:37 ║ AP-3c9b33d0 ║
║ 64:70:02:29:16:AE ║ 21/03/2014 12:32 ║ AP-3c9b33d0 ║
║ B0:02:94:1D:3B:43 ║ 21/03/2014 12:46 ║ AP-5c9b33d0 ║
║ B4:F0:AB:C2:F6:92 ║ 21/03/2014 12:46 ║ AP-3c9b33d0 ║
║ 00:26:AB:F1:7C:EE ║ 21/03/2014 12:45 ║ AP-5c9b33d0 ║
║ B0:02:94:1D:3B:43 ║ 21/03/2014 12:45 ║ AP-4c9b33d0 ║
║ 1C:C1:DE:6A:90:47 ║ 21/03/2014 12:56 ║ AP-4c9b33d0 ║
║ B4:F0:AB:C2:F6:92 ║ 21/03/2014 13:02 ║ AP-3c9b33d0 ║
║ 00:26:AB:F1:7C:EE ║ 21/03/2014 13:07 ║ AP-4c9b33d0 ║
╚═══════════════════╩══════════════════╩═════════════╝
```

What I now want to do is find out from this list what devices(`mac`) have been reported by more than one Access Point(`reportedby`).

I am in a flat spin, my mind has gone completely blank. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: +1 for nicely presenting your question!

Comment: You cannot get this result with this `SELECT`

Comment: btw not related to your question but it's not a good practice to name the column with reserved key of mysql (alter timestamp column)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your query should look like this:

```
SELECT mac 
FROM TBLWiFi 
WHERE TIMESTAMP >= DATE_SUB( NOW( ) , INTERVAL 1 HOUR )
GROUP BY  mac 
HAVING COUNT( mac ) > 1 ;
```

In the `having` clause, the condition on `timestamp` compares only one `timestamp` per `mac`.  The one being compared comes from an arbitrary row.

To get more than one access point, change the `having` clause to:

```
HAVING COUNT(mac) > 1 and
       COUNT(DISTINCT reportedby) > 1;
```

Actually, if there is more than one `reportedby` then there is more than one row, so this will suffice:

```
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT reportedby) > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT mac 
  FROM TBLWiFi 
GROUP BY 
       mac 
HAVING COUNT( reportedby ) >1 
       AND TIMESTAMP >= DATE_SUB( NOW( ) , INTERVAL 1 HOUR ))
```

I'm not sure why you wanted to have `COUNT (mac) > 1...` Instead I replaced it with reportedby... `SELECT` withing a `SELECT` or a `JOINT` can be used when you are extracting data from 2 or more tables...hope this would help you... :-)